# How to avoid removal of dataframe if remove vector is empty?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I need to remove some rows in a dataframe.

My code looks like this :

```
remove <- ...  
dataset <- dataset[-remove,]
```

Though, depending on the context, my `remove` vector might be empty.
When it is empty, every row of my dataframe is removed.

How could I modify this for that, in this case, no row is being removed?

Comment: can you provide reproducible example?

Comment: @Marcelin Tworski if this answer helped, please consider selecting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets community know the answer worked and the issue is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to just check if the vector is empty before executing the statement.

If `remove` is a `data.frame`, the correct function is `nrow()` or `NROW()`.

If `remove` is a `vector`, you can choose between `length()` and `NROW()`.

So either way, this piece of code will solve your problem:

```
if(NROW(remove)>0) dataset <- dataset[-remove,]
```

However, please note that `nrow()` will work only work for `data.frame` while `NROW()` will work for both `data.frame` and `vector`. 
`length()` is also a valid function for `data.frame` but it returns the number of columns in the `data.frame`.

While the last note might sound redundant here, it is useful to keep in mind since you might find yourself in a situation in which a loop appears to be not working properly and this is the solution.

For the sake of completeness, see the example code below:

```
v1 <- seq(1:10)
v2 <- seq(1:10)
length(v1)
# output = 10
NROW(v1)
# output = 10
nrow(v1)
# output = NULL
df <- data.frame(v1,v2)
NROW(df)
# output = 10
nrow(df)
# output = 10
length(df)
# output = 2
```

Comment: Just an addition: There is also the `NROW()` function which does the same as `nrow()` treating a vector as 1-column matrix. So, `NROW()` can be used with both vectors and data.frames instead of `length()` and `nrow()`. Please, feel free to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a little workaround, check which rows to keep (`setdiff()` to all rows and `remove`, i.e. all rows except which are to be removed):

```
dataset[setdiff(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), remove),]
```